# How to escape double brackets in Hyde markdown syntax

Tags: python, hyde

When using the [Hyde](http://hyde.github.io/) static webpage generator I have Python code with double brackets

```
{% syntax %}
var[["some-string"]] = foo
{% endsyntax %}
```

This renders oddly because `[["foo"]]` is special Hyde markdown.

Normal escaping (e.g. through the use of [HTML escape characters](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php?PHPSESSID=8cbbddde9a9c9825467546f1c98fe119)) fails because we're inside of a syntax block.

How does one escape characters within a Hyde syntax block?